# Efeito de galeria android studio

Tags: java, android, mobile

estou com um probleminha que não estou encontrando a resposta, queria fazer uma galeria com esse efeito: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] mas não estou conseguindo alguém teria uma dica de como eu posso alcançar tal efeito?

Comment: Inclua o seu código para que seja possível ver o que está errado e ajudar a resolver.

Comment: O que você já tem?